# My page is loading everytime i enter a letter in search in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Actually i am trying to implement a search text field, which i have done the search field is working almost properly but my page is getting reloaded everytime i am entering a letter. How can i overcome the issue, the gif attached may help you regarding the error. I don't want to reload the page everytime rather i want the property cards to get sorted and showed according to the query.

Here is the code:

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ranv1/strings/images.dart';

import '../Detailed Pages/Apartment Detailed Page.dart';
import '../Detailed Pages/Villa Detailed Page.dart';
import '../cardFiles/CommercialCard.dart';
import '../cardFiles/apartmentCard.dart';
import '../cardFiles/farmLandCard.dart';
import '../cardFiles/plotCard.dart';
import '../cardFiles/villaCard.dart';

class BuilderSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BuilderSearchState createState() => _BuilderSearchState();
}

class _BuilderSearchState extends State<BuilderSearch> {
  String propertyTitle = '';
  String propertyDescription = '';
  String propertyAddress = '';
  String propertyBedRooms = '';
  String propertyBathRooms = '';
  String propertyArea = '';
  String propertyPrice = '';
  final List<String> areaInSqft = [];
  List<DocumentSnapshot> filteredData = [];
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late final User _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Image.asset(
            rlogo,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 30,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Color(0xFF242A38),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore
              .collection('builderData')
              .where('Builder Id', isEqualTo: _user.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text('Loading...');
            }

            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    'Search Your Listings',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          searchController.clear();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (query) {
                      setState(() {
                        filteredData = snapshot.data!.docs.where((document) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> data =
                              document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          return data['Property Title']
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .contains(query.toLowerCase());
                        }).toList();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    children: filteredData.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> data =
                          document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (data['Property Type'] == 'Apartment') {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ApartmentDetailsPage(
                                  propertyTitle: data['Property Title'] ?? '',
                                  maxInSqft: data['Max Sqft'] ?? '',
                                  minInSqft: data['Min Sqft'] ?? '',
                                  propertyDescription:
                                      data['Property Description'] ?? '',
                                  propertyCover: data['Property Cover'] ?? '',
                                  propertyImages: data['Property Images'] ?? [],
                                  documentId: document.id,
                                  propertyType: data['Property Type'] ?? '',
                                  areaInSqft: data['Area Sqft'] ?? '',
                                  propertyStatus: data['Property Status'] ?? '',
                                  totalUnits: data['Total Units'] ?? '',
                                  launchDate: data['Launch Date'] ?? '',
                                  oneBhk: data['One Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  twoBhk: data['Two Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  threeBhk: data['Three Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  totalProjectArea:
                                      data['Total Project Area'] ?? '',
                                  fourBhk: data['Four Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  fivePlusBhk: data['FivePlus Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  selectedUnits: data['Selected Units'] ?? '',
                                  possessDate: data['Possession Date'] ?? '',
                                  propertyReraId: data['Rera Id'] ?? '',
                                  totalFloors: data['Total Floors'] ?? '',
                                  pricePerSqft: data['Price Sqft'],
                                  propertyAddress:
                                      data['Property Address'] ?? '',
                                  img1: data['Image 1'] ?? '',
                                  img2: data['Image 2'] ?? '',
                                  img3: data['Image 3'] ?? '',
                                  img4: data['Image 4'] ?? '',
                                  img5: data['Image 5'] ?? '',
                                  gMapLink: data['Google Maps Link'] ?? '',
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if (data['Property Type'] == 'Villa') {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => VillaDetailsPage(
                                  propertyTitle: data['Property Title'] ?? '',
                                  propertyDescription:
                                      data['Property Description'] ?? '',
                                  propertyCover: data['Property Cover'] ?? '',
                                  propertyImages: data['Property Images'] ?? [],
                                  documentId: document.id,
                                  propertyType: data['Property Type'] ?? '',
                                  propertyStatus: data['Property Status'] ?? '',
                                  totalUnits: data['Total Units'] ?? '',
                                  launchDate: data['Launch Date'] ?? '',
                                  oneBhk: data['One Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  twoBhk: data['Two Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  threeBhk: data['Three Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  totalProjectArea:
                                      data['Total Project Area'] ?? '',
                                  fourBhk: data['Four Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  fivePlusBhk: data['FivePlus Bhk'] ?? '',
                                  selectedUnits: data['Selected Units'] ?? '',
                                  possessDate: data['Possession Date'] ?? '',
                                  propertyReraId: data['Rera Id'] ?? '',
                                  totalFloors: data['Total Floors'] ?? '',
                                  propertyAddress:
                                      data['Property Address'] ?? '',
                                  img1: data['Image 1'] ?? '',
                                  img2: data['Image 2'] ?? '',
                                  img3: data['Image 3'] ?? '',
                                  img4: data['Image 4'] ?? '',
                                  img5: data['Image 5'] ?? '',
                                  totalPrice: data['Total Price'] ?? '',
                                  landInSqyd: data['Land Sqyd'] ?? '',
                                  maxInSqyd: data['Max Sqyd'] ?? '',
                                  minInSqyd: data['Min Sqyd'] ?? '',
                                  gMapLink: data['Google Maps Link'] ?? '',
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                if (data['Property Type'] == 'Apartment')
                                  ApartmentCard(data: data),
                                if (data['Property Type'] == 'Villa')
                                  VillaCard(data: data),
                                if (data['Property Type'] == 'Plot')
                                  PlotCard(data: data),
                                if (data['Property Type'] == 'Farm Land')
                                  FarmLandCard(data: data),
                                if (data['Property Type'] == 'Commercial')
                                  CommercialCard(data: data),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }[![The image is the implementation of the search and the issue which is being faced by me][1]][1]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you create every time a new stream

```
firestore
              .collection('builderData')
              .where('Builder Id', isEqualTo: _user.uid)
              .snapshots()
```

On every rebuild with setState or other state management solutions this stream will be recreated.

So do the following:

Create a variable inside your class which holds the streams and pass it into the StreamBuilder

```
Stream myStream = firestore
              .collection('builderData')
              .where('Builder Id', isEqualTo: _user.uid)
              .snapshots();
```

And pass it to the StreamBuilder

```
stream: myStream,
```

Here is a cool video from Randal Schwartz with a  small example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg